# Подписаться/отписаться от автора поста в django

Tags: python, django

нужна помощь, создаю систему подписки/отписки от пользователей блога по аналогии с Твитером или Инстаграмм. То есть любой зарегистрированный пользователь на сайте может подписываться/отписаться от любого пользователя. При нажатии на кнопку отписаться/подписаться выдает ошибку HTTP ERROR 405.
Вот код модели:

```
class Author(AbstractUser):
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/profile/")
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    facebook_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    twitter_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    instagram_url = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followed_by", symmetrical=False, blank=True)

    def count_followers(self):
        return self.follows.count()

    def count_following(self):
        return Author.objects.filter(follows=self).count()
```

Код вьюшки:

```
class AuthorDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Author
    template_name = "registration/author_detail.html"


def follow_user(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        profile = Author.objects.get(user_id=pk)
        if request.method == "POST":
            current_user_profile = request.user.profile
            action = request.POST["follow"]
            if action == "unfollow":
                current_user_profile.follows.remove(profile)
            elif action == "follow":
                current_user_profile.follows.add(profile)
            current_user_profile.save()
        return render(request, "registration/author_detail.html", {"profile": profile})
```

код html странички:

```
<form method=POST>
          {% csrf_token %}
          {% if author in author.follows.all %}
            <button class="btn btn-outline-danger" name="follow"
                    value="unfollow" type="submit">Unfollow @{{ author.username | lower }}
            </button>
          {% else %}
           <button class="btn btn-outline-success" name="follow"
                    value="follow" type="submit"> Follow @{{ author.username | lower }}
            </button>
          {% endif %}
        </form>
```

Не могу понять, где ошибка?